# Push values from each element to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, each

I'm creating a JSON array out of values from each input field, but there are no elements saved in the array and the alert(json) doesn't fire in the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a (not working fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/PRnPd/

I get this console error when loading the page, at the line of the JSON.stringify: "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."

HTML

```
<div class="question-holder">
<div>
<label>First Question</label>
<input type="text" value="First" />   
</div>
<div>
 <label>Second Question</label>
<input type="text" value="Second" />   
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="submit-holder">
 <div>
 <label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="txtName" value="John Doe" />   
 </div>
 <div>
 <label>E-mail</label>
<input type="email" name="txtEmail" value="john@doe.com" />   
</div>
<div>
 <label>Second Question</label>
<input type="text" value="Second" />   
 </div>
 </div>
<button class="get_json">Get JSON</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.get_json', function () { 

        var json = [];

        var Submission = [];

        var Answer = [];

        $('.question-holder').find('input').each(function(){
        answer = $(this).val()
        label = $(this).closest('li').find('label')

        Answer.push({
        Answers: answer,
        Label: label
        });         

        });

        $('.submit-holder').find('input').each(function(){
            answer = $(this).val()
            input_name = $(this).attr('name')
            label = $(this).closest('li').find('label')

            Submission.push({
            Question: label,
            Input_Name: input_name,
            Submitted_data: answer
            });                         
        });

        json.push({
        Submission: Submission,
        Answers: Answer,
        Motivation: $('.motivation').val()
        });

        json = JSON.stringify({json: json}, null, "\t");        

       alert(json)
 });
```

Comment: fiddle is working fine for me...

Comment: your jsfiddle works.. just need to add jquery reference

Comment: After enabling jQuery in the fiddle, I get the error _TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON_

Comment: I suspect the problem is trying to put `label` into the JSON. This is a jQuery collection, and it has lots of references to jQuery internal data structures. Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks, I loaded the Jquery aswell, and it did not work, also I change the variable name of "label" to "input_label", but didn't do it, am I prepering the JSON structure correct or do I fail somewhere?

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: try to comment the `Label : label` and `Question : label` elements in JSON and you will see that it works. That is the problem as Barmar said

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar and @John! It made it to remove "label"! I'll get it to work from here, good to know, thanks again!